# Is there any syntax in NSPredicate like "limit(location, length)" in SQLite?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

Assuming that I have an array that contains 25 objects within.
How can I do to filter the array with range from 20 to 30?
I know that I can use - subarrayWithRange:.
But if the range is out of the existed object range, then it will be crashed.

In SQLite we can use limit(location, length) to retrieve result.
So I think is there a way that I can approach this?

**Edit:**

I may express the question a little fuzzy, is there any syntax in NSPredicate like "limit(location, length)" in SQLite? then I don't need to check the max anymore?

Comment: Before sending the message subarrayWithRange, check if the range is valid. NSPredicate is pretty optimized if the predicate is not complex 25 objects is not a limiti

Comment: why dont you just query the length of the array and limit the upper bound to that retrieved length?

Answer (score 0):

Get count of your array, then set range max as array.count. If array.count is less than the range this should avoid crashes. Else if array.count is = with predefined range max this is another case. When array.count is over predefined range max there is no problem. Hope this helps.

Comment: That's exactly how I do now, but my question is, is there any syntax in NSPredicate like "limit(location, length)" in SQLite? then I don't need to check the max anymore?